# react-bootstrap-multiselect is not working poroperly

Tags: reactjs

```
import React from 'react';
import Multiselect from 'react-bootstrap-multiselect';

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      list: [{value:'One',selected:true},{value:'Two'},{value:'Three'},{value:'Four',label:'Four Label'}]
    }
  }


  render(){
    return (
        <Multiselect data={this.state.list} multiple />
    );
  }
}

export default Test2;
```

Here i am using react-bootstrap-multiselect

The ui is not coming properly.

Am i missing something?

PLease have a look.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try removing label attribute,

```
import React from 'react';
import Multiselect from 'react-bootstrap-multiselect';

class Test2 extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      list: [{value:'One',selected:true},{value:'Two'},{value:'Three'},{value:'Four'}]
    }
  }


  render(){
    return (
        <Multiselect data={this.state.list} multiple />
    );
  }
}

export default Test2;
```